# Android Genymotion VM logcat runs into infinite loop

Tags: android, logcat, genymotion

Whenever I run my app on the **Genymotion (V2.3) emulator** (any Android version), it runs into an infinite loop with this error printing in the **logcat** continuously:

```
11-10 04:33:55.542: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:55.902: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:55.962: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.014: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.066: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.114: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.166: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.210: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.266: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.314: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.362: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.410: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.470: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.518: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.562: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.614: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.662: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.714: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
11-10 04:33:56.750: E/eglCodecCommon(2775): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
```

My App works fine, but I am unable to print anything in logcat or even read anything else in it in case of any exceptions. I have no idea what is this about or what is causing it. I tried to find online without any luck.

**UPDATE**:
I realized that this happens whenever I show banner ads (from Google admob sdk, or Leadbolt sdk) in my Activity.

Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: No, I didn't! It's very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OK.  Just ignore these messages.

the root cause is caused by having checked the "USE GPU Host" or similar options in your Genymotion. If this options disabled, the error will gone, but the performance is not good. ( or much worse)

refer to:  [How to solve webview error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450746/how-to-solve-webview-error)

Answer (score 7):

I think  your genymotion emulator doesnot have access to host gpu.Since your page has some graphics  Open GL will not work.

You can solve this by adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Not sure turning off hardware acceleration across your entire app just to avoid a genymmotion logcat message is a good idea

Comment: There will be some option to provide gpu access