# How to solve webview error

Tags: java, android

I have some error in logcat that I don't know how to fix it.I need some help to find solution.

[Error](http://uupload.ir/files/np00_error.png)

```
04-04 15:49:37.143    2088-2107/com.exercise.AndroidHTML W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
04-04 15:49:37.153    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8eab450, tid 2088
04-04 15:49:37.293    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 76K, 5% free 3423K/3576K, paused 5ms, total 7ms
04-04 15:49:37.323    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3643K/3800K, paused 4ms, total 7ms
04-04 15:49:37.323    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.047MB for 2536932-byte allocation
04-04 15:49:37.343    2088-2102/com.exercise.AndroidHTML D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 6119K/6280K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
04-04 15:49:37.733    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-04 15:49:37.733    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-04 15:49:37.763    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
04-04 15:49:38.113    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
04-04 15:49:38.763    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:38.773    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:38.863    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
04-04 15:49:39.063    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
04-04 15:49:39.103    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:39.153    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:39.153    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:39.173    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:39.183    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:39.193    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:39.233    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:40.913    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:40.923    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:40.943    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:41.013    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(132)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ReadDB'", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (132)
04-04 15:49:41.923    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-04 15:49:41.923    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:41.933    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:42.063    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:42.133    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:42.143    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:42.153    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:42.273    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
04-04 15:49:42.283    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
04-04 15:49:43.103    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
04-04 15:49:43.103    2088-2088/com.exercise.AndroidHTML I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Please post logcat here .

Comment: sorry.but I don't know how insert logcat in code

Answer (score 14):

The error occurs only with the Android emulator, and is caused by having checked the "Use GPU Host" in the Android Virtual Device Manager. If you disable this option, the error will disappear, but the emulator will have a much worse performance.

The other thing you can do is add this to the logcat filter to remove these messages:

Log Tag (regex): `^(?!(eglCodecCommon))`

I hope it helped you

Comment: just remove the spaces from regex and it will work `^(?!(eglCodecCommon))`
http://imgur.com/a/E5AkL

Answer (score -1):

I also have problem before, I trying to load Chatango on webview, then my problem solved using this code, try this:

```
    import android.webkit.WebSettings; //dont forget import WebSettings
```

then webView attribute:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    WebSettings websettings = webView.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    websettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; C1905 Build/15.1.C.2.8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36");
    webView.loadUrl(yourUrltoLoad);
```